# How to take care of "List out of index" error in python?

Tags: python, list

I have list `socpu` and I am calculating another list from this list in such a way:

```
Import logging    
socpu = [12,23,34,45,43,32,21,23,44,32,11,22,55,33]
try:
    chargeAndDischarge = [socpu[i+1]-socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu))]
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
    print(e) 
print(chargeAndDischarge)
```

As in this program I am using socpu[i+1] which will ultimatly `List out of index` error in the end, that's why I put it in the `try and except` block but is there any alternative way for that ? plus even after putting it in the `Try and except` block, this gives and error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'chargeAndDischarge' referenced before assignment
```

Expected ans:

```
chargeAndDischarge = [11,11,11,-2,-11,-11,2,21,-12,-21,11,33,-22]
```

can anyone help?

Comment: `chargeAndDischarge = [socpu[i+1]-socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu)-1)]` just add  -1 after `len(socpu)`. I don't see any problem. Or, you wanted something different?

Comment: "`List out of index`"? That sounds wrong. Are you sure?

Comment: yeah that's fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because your looping from 0 to len(socpu), but you're actually accessing to the ith+1 element. The best way to solve this is by looping to len(socpu)-1.

```
Import logging    
socpu = [12,23,34,45,43,32,21,23,44,32,11,22,55,33]

chargeAndDischarge = [socpu[i+1] - socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu) - 1)]
print(chargeAndDischarge)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to:

```
chargeAndDischarge = [socpu[i+1]-socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu)-1)]
```

The length of the difference list needs to be one less than the length of the original list.  Subtracting `1` from the length accomplishes this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
socpu = [12,23,34,45,43,32,21,23,44,32,11,22,55,33]
print([n-m for m, n in zip(socpu, socpu[1:])])
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 11, 11, -2, -11, -11, 2, 21, -12, -21, 11, 33, -22]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add conditional to the list comprehension:

```
chargeAndDischarge = [socpu[i+1] - socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu)) if i+1 <= len(socpu)]
```

If you know numpy, you can simply use numpy array and turn it to list:

```
import numpy as np
chargeAndDischarge = np.diff(socpu).tolist()
```

In the above code, np.diff will turn socpu from list to numpy array and do the subtraction automatically. Finally, the tolist() method can turn the resultant numpy array to the original list

Answer (score 1):

Though many have given very good logic, I still want to share my logic :)

```
socpu = [12,23,34,45,43,32,21,23,44,32,11,22,55,33]
result = [socpu[i+1] - socpu[i] for i in range(len(socpu)) if (len(socpu)-1 != i)]
print(result)
```

Refer to the below screenshot for the output.

[image]